# I have a foreach loop but I need to include information which is in another array in it as well

Tags: php, laravel

The code below is used to delete all checked categories in the checkbox, however, I have a hidden input field for each checkbox that contains the file name of the image used as thumbnail and since I don't want to make queries to get the file name, I'm passing it as hidden input.

So `$request['categoryFiles']` contains the file name for each `$request['categories']`, however, I'm not sure how to use that array in the `foreach` so that I can fill `Storage::delete('public/uploads/categories/'.???);` with the correct index of the `$request['categoryFiles']` array.

The ??? have to be replaced with something like `$request['categoryFiles'][0]`, `$request['categoryFiles'][1]`, etc for as long as the `foreach` is looping

```
public function deleteCategories(Request $request){

    if (!Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
            return redirect()->back();
    } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
        $categories = $request['categories'];
        $categoryFiles = $request['categoryFiles'];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/categories/'.???);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/categories/thumbnails/'.???);
        }
        Category::whereIn('id', $categories)->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the key from the categories to match against the other array...

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
    Storage::delete('public/uploads/categories/'.$categoryFiles[$key]);
    Storage::delete('public/uploads/categories/thumbnails/'.$categoryFiles[$key]);
}
```